# How to change joomla url suffix

Tags: joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I am using Joomla Sef URLs and its working fine except that i need '.htm' suffix instead of '.html', please help.

currently my URLs appear like :

```
www.mysite.com/my-page.html
```

I want it to be like

```
www.mysite.com/my-page.htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use one of the 3rd Party Search Engine Friendly link extensions: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem by purchasing sh404SEF. It worked for my requirement and some more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a patch. Tested on my Joomla 1.5.9 (standard bundled SEF):

```
Index: includes/router.php
===================================================================
--- includes/router.php (revision 13023)
+++ includes/router.php (working copy)
@@ -57,8 +57,13 @@
            {
                if($suffix = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
                {
-                   $path = str_replace('.'.$suffix, '', $path);
-                   $vars['format'] = $suffix;
+                   if ($suffix == 'htm') {
+                       $path = str_replace('.'.$suffix, '', $path);
+                       $vars['format'] = 'html';
+                   } else {
+                       $path = str_replace('.'.$suffix, '', $path);
+                       $vars['format'] = $suffix;
+                   }
                }
            }
        }
@@ -93,7 +98,8 @@
            {
                if($format = $uri->getVar('format', 'html'))
                {
-                   $route .= '.'.$format;
+                   //$route .= '.'.$format;
+                   $route .= '.htm';
                    $uri->delVar('format');
                }
            }
```